# How to install R 3.5.1 on raspbian stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch

The version of "R" in the default repositories is R 3.3.3, but this version is more than a year old. How can I install the latest version? On CRAN there is a repository for Debian stretch, but I can't fetch the signing key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

- [compile from source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=221861)